# return value(s) with LABjs

Tags: javascript, labjs

So i have this function i want to run after dynamically loading a script with $LABjs, but LABjs does not support return values, it needs to return itself to be able chain load more scripts and wait.. fair enough. But then how do i get the return value of my function?

```
var hub;

var test = function() {
  return $LAB.script('DataUI/ckeditor/ckeditor.js').wait(function() {
    hub = "yikes!";
  });

  return hub;
}

console.log(test());
```

This returns undefined, because the test function returns the hub variable immediately. Is there a way to force LABjs to wait, so i can get my value?

**Suggestions:**

1. There should really be a switch to force sync loading, like jQuery allows with AJAX. Or $LABjs could return an array of the values returned from it's scripts/waits.
2. Return a promise so i can wait for my variable to be populated with the expected value.

Comment: I should go with returning a promise so that callers of the function can chain `test().wait(function(){ /* code here */ })`.